# Type::Tiny and deep coercions

Tags: perl, moo

I'm trying to get deep coercions work with `Type::Tiny` without any success. From the [manual](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/Type-Tiny/lib/Type/Tiny/Manual/Coercions.pod#Deep-Coercions) it's said that:

"Certain parameterized type constraints can automatically acquire
coercions if their parameters have coercions. For example: 
`ArrayRef[Int->plus_coercions(Num, q{int($_)}) ]` 
... does what you mean!"

What I try to accomplish is getting something like this "do what I mean":

```
package Person;
use Types::Standard -types;
use Moo;

has name => (is => 'ro', isa => Str);

package Family;
use Types::Standard -types;
use Moo;

has members => (is => 'ro', isa => ArrayRef[InstanceOf['Person']]);

package main;

my $family = Family->new(members => [
  'mom',
  Person->new(name => 'dad'),
  Person->new(name => 'girl'),
  'dog'
]);
```

When instantiating `Family` with elements that are a `Str` they should be automatically be coerced into `Person` objects. I've tried a range of different ideas (plus_coercions, Type libraries, etc) without any luck. They all fail in the same way.

When using plus_coercions (from `Str` to `Object`)

```
package Family;

has members => (
  is => 'ro',
  isa => ArrayRef[ Object->plus_coercions(Str, q{ Person->new(name => $_) }) ],
);
```

Type::Tiny throws an exception:

```
Reference ["mom",bless( {"name" => "dad"}, 'Person' ),bless( {"name" =...] did not pass type constraint "ArrayRef[Object]" (in $args->{"members"})
"ArrayRef[Object]" constrains each value in the array with "Object"
"Object" is a subtype of "Object"
"Object" is a subtype of "Ref"
Value "mom" did not pass type constraint "Ref" (in $args->{"members"}->[0])
"Ref" is defined as: (!!ref($_))
```

I know I could get around this by modifying the arguments to `Family->new` using a `BUILDARGS` sub in `Family`, but it would be neat if Type::Tiny could do that automatically.

**Update**

Thanks to Tobys friendly help, I got this working. The only part that troubled me a bit was the use of `ArrayRef[Object]` instead of the correct `ArrayRef[InstanceOf['Person']]` (`InstanceOf` doesn't have any `plus_coercions`). With `Object` an instance of *any* class could have been inserted into `members`, and that is certainly not what you want.

Got around that by making a `class_type`. Here's the full working code:

```
package Person;
use Types::Standard -types;
use Moo;

has name => (is => 'ro', isa => Str);

package Family;
use Types::Standard -types;
use Type::Utils -all;
use Moo;

my $Person = class_type { class => 'Person' };

my $Members = ArrayRef[
  $Person->plus_coercions(Str, q{ Person->new(name => $_) })
];

has members => (
  is     => 'ro',
  isa    => $Members,
  coerce => $Members->coercion,
);

sub list { join(', ', map { $_->name } @{ $_[0]->members }) }

package main;

my $family = Family->new(members => [
  'mom',
  Person->new(name => 'dad'),
  Person->new(name => 'girl'),
  'dog'
]);

print $family->list, "\n";
```

Which nicely prints `mom, dad, girl, dog` when run.

Comment: `InstanceOf` certainly does have `plus_coercions`. However, doing `InstanceOf["Person"]->plus_coercions(...)` will try to call a method on an unblessed arrayref because of Perl operator precedence. It can be sorted out by adding some parentheses: `(InstanceOf["Person"])->plus_coercions(...)`.

Comment: Aaah, of course. Anyway, using a `class_type` lead to nice and tidy code. A `ArrayRef[InstanceOf['Class::Name::Which::Is::Very::Long']]` is quite unwieldy. But it's good to know more than one way to do it. As always!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Moose/Moo/Mouse attributes don't coerce by default, so even though the type constraint *has* a coercion, you need to tell the attribute to *use* that coercion!

If you were using Moose or Mouse, you could do:

```
has members => (
  is     => 'ro',
  isa    => ArrayRef[ Object->plus_coercions(Str, q{ Person->new(name => $_) }) ],
  coerce => 1,
);
```

But Moo doesn't support `coerce=>1`; instead it expects a coderef or overloaded object to act as the coercion. Type::Tiny can provide you with a suitable overloaded object by calling `$type->coercion`.

```
# Let's store the type constraint in a variable to avoid repetition...
my $type = ArrayRef[
  Object->plus_coercions(  Str, q{Person->new(name => $_)}  )
];

has members => (
  is     => 'ro',
  isa    => $type,
  coerce => $type->coercion,
);
```